# unityでwebカメラの映像が写りません

Tags: unity3d, camera

unityとvuforiaで簡単なARのプログラムを作ろうとしています。しかし、実行させようとすると、パソコンのwebカメラは起動するのですが、画面は真っ暗なままで何も写りません(画像１)。ARCameraの設定は画像のとおりにしてあります(画像２)(特に何もいじっていません)。また、Vuforia Behavior内でvuforiaを無効にしているわけでもありません。別のアプリではwebカメラがちゃんと使えるのでたぶんunityの設定とかだと思っているのですが、どうすればカメラが写るようになりますか？
追記 使用PCはacerのAspire R3-131T、OSはWindows10、カメラはHDWebCam、unityはPersonalでバージョンは2018.1.6f1、vuforiaのバージョンは7.1.35です。[image: 画像１ プログラムの実行結果][image: 画像２ ARCameraの設定]

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　可能であれば、投稿末尾に環境の情報を追記して頂けませんか？　OS、カメラ、Unity のバージョン、ライブラリのバージョンなどの情報があると、回答者が問題を再現しやすくなります。質問文の下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: SRM さん、編集の提案をいただきましたが、質問者であれば自分の質問を自由に編集できます。私は編集の提案を承認できる立場にありますが、質問者ご本人なのか確認できないため提案を承認できません。もしアカウントが2つに分かれてしまったということであれば、ヘルプセンターの[こちらのページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)を元にアカウントをご統合ください。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13192842823

Comment: nekketsuuuさんに従い、情報を分かる範囲で追加しました。

Comment: マルチポストですが、それも私が投稿したもので、未だに返答が無いものです…。

Comment: @SRM さん、追記ありがとうございます！　また、マルチポストそれ自体はスタック・オーバーフローで禁止されているわけではありませんが、マルチポストする場合は各サイトで情報を統一して頂けると回答者の助けになります。より詳しい事情については[マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/19110)をご覧ください。

Comment: nekketsuuuさん、いつもこのサイトの使い方など教えてくださり、ありがとうございます。マルチポストの方でも情報を統一するようにします。

Comment: 解決しました。Unityのバージョンを5.4.0f3にしたら無事カメラが写りました。